# TypeError: create() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

Here is my code file with name is CreateNode.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import py2neo

from py2neo import Graph, Node

def createNodeWithLabelProperties():
        print("Start Create label with prperties")
        py2neo.authenticate ("localhost:7474", "neo4j", "XXXXXXX")
        graph = Graph("http://localhost:7474/db/data")
        #Create Node with properties
        node1 = Node("LableFirst", name="Chuvindra Singh", age="27")
        #create Node with 2 label
        node2 = Node("Labelfirst", "LabelSecond",name="Koki Sing", age="27")
        node3 = Node("Labelk", "LabelB",name="Manzil", age="27")
        #now use Graph Object to create node
        resultNodes = graph.create(node1, node2, node3)
        for index in range(len(resultNodes)):
                print("Created Node - ", index, ", ", resultNodes[inedx])
                print("End Printing the node")

if __name__ =='__main__':
        print("start Creating nodes")
        createNodeWithLabelProperties()
        print("End Creating nodes")
```

When I run this file then it show error :

```
start Creating nodes
    Start Create label with prperties
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "CreateNode.py", line 23, in <module>
        createNodeWithLabelProperties()
      File "CreateNode.py", line 16, in createNodeWithLabelProperties
        resultNodes = graph.create(node1, node2, node3)
    TypeError: create() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Where is mistake in code? i could not understand?Can you some one help me out?

Answer (score 3):

In py2neo v3, the `create` method (and all similar methods) take only a single argument, which can be any graphy object (see the [manual page on types](http://py2neo.org/v3/types.html)). You can therefore create multiple nodes by unioning them into a subgraph to pass as the argument. In your case, you'll want something like:

```
graph.create(node1 | node2 | node3)
```

Comment: Thanks, can you suggest any source where i can learn py2neo version 3, in document there is no specific details to use code. I am reading a book that have only details of v2.

Comment: I was unaware of any books that contained details of either version! The documentation I wrote for the project is here -> http://py2neo.org/v3/

Answer (score 1):

This message:

```
TypeError: create() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

refers to this call:

```
graph.create(node1, node2, node3)
```

The call is passing four arguments (counting the invocant `graph` as well as `node1`, `node2`, and `node3`) to the `create` method, but that method only expects two (including the invocant).

Upon reviewing the API documentation, I believe that you are using version 3 of py2neo (documented [here](http://py2neo.org/v3/database.html#the-graph)), in which `Graph.create` takes only a single non-invocant parameter, but trying to call it as if it were version 2 (documented [here](http://py2neo.org/2.0/essentials.html)), where it can take more than one.

Comment: Thanks @mark but No, its not accepting list arguments, create is method of Graph class and can accept more then one arguments.

Comment: In py2neo v2, yes. You appear to be using py2neo v3.  See edit.